# Understanding Jquery-Cropper units

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropper

I'm making a project using jquery-cropper (https://fengyuanchen.github.io/jquery-cropper/).

I need to get the coordinates of the crop rectangle. The method `getCropBoxData()` return those coordinates, but I can't get what units it's using, and the documentation doesn't mention them.

Check the picture of the demo page I'm attaching. The fields at the right show the current position of the crop in pixels, but if you press [Get Crop Box Data], you get totally different values at the bottom. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I think they're pixels like the values in the table on the right. Some are decimal because they're calculated because of the fixed 16:9 ratio. Click the [Free] ratio button, change one of the values in the line, like "width:" from 552 to 100, and click [Set Crop Box Data]. The crop box will change to the new width.

Comment: I think they are not pixels, because the relation is different. At the right, X is greater than Y, but at the bottom is the opposite.

Comment: BTW, I found that [Get Data] returns the values in pixels like the fields at the right. So, I'm using those values while I decipher what [Get Crop Box Data] returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question. For this specific issue, I found that `getData` method returns the crop coordinates in pixels, the same values that appear at the right in the demo page. This should be useful for anybody that need to get the crop info. About `getCropBoxData`, still not sure what units are those.

Comment: I noticed when you click [Zoom to 100%] that the [Get Data] width and height match the crop box width and height. So crop box data must be multiplied by the zoom %.